# Send mail using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have been trying to find out if MSbuild can send an email to the developers just like NANT.
I don't see any option in mSbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an email task in the  [MSbuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) collection. This is a set of open source MSBuild tasks - lots of goodies there.

Comment: Mail option is not coming for me somehow

Comment: What do you mean? Perhaps this thread will help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/fed4fad6-21a8-4b9b-abcb-04c2e1c56076

Comment: I am trying to modify on tfsbuild.proj by adding this line of code:
<Target Name="SendMailToDevelopers">
    <Mail option is not coming for me. 
</Target>

Do let me know, If I doing something wrong

Comment: I was looking into that, tried the same thing. But mail option is not coming for me, as I wrote above.

Comment: @alice7 - are you looking for intellisense to come up? It will not come up automatically for the community tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been answered, but if you install the power tools you get an alerts option in the Team Explorer.

That alerts has several TFS Based options to send emails (on fail, on succeed).